# Macbook Air webcam not working

Tags: release-loki, macbook, macintosh, webcam

I've installed eOS loki on a USB via unetbootin.  Loki is just awesome BTW (aside from some bugs)!

When I run it on my Toshiba Portege the webcam works fine, but when I run it on my Macbook Air, Camera says no compatible device found...

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this one?  `/dev/video0` doesn't exist but when I run `lsmod` "video" is listed as "1" ie it should be active...

Comment: Update: tried this tutorial https://turanct.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/use-your-macs-isight-on-ubuntu/ to install isight firmware, still no luck...

Answer (score 1):

`bcwc_pcie` is an experimental "Linux driver for the Facetime HD (Broadcom 1570) PCIe webcam found in recent Macbooks". Install directions [here](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki)!

Comment: Though I have encountered that the webcam takes an awfully long time to load...